# Is my claim true for the range of the given function (inequality)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, solution-verification, maxima-minima

I have two 2-variable real functions
$$-2 \;\leq \;f_1(x,y) \;\;\leq 5,$$
$$-1 \;\;\leq \;f_2(x,y)\;\; \leq 4,$$
I want to have a general condition for the range of this function
$$   a_1 \;f_1(x,y)+a_2\;f_2(x,y) ,\quad \text{for} \quad a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}.$$
According to the inequality rules, can I claim that the following conditions hold?
$$ -2\,a_1-a_2 \;\;\leq\;\; a_1 \;f_1(x,y)+a_2\;f_2(x,y) \;\;\leq \;\;\;5\,a_1+4\,a_2,\quad \text{if} \quad a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}^+$$
$$ -2\,a_1-a_2 \;\;\geq\;\; a_1 \;f_1(x,y)+a_2\;f_2(x,y) \;\;\geq \;\;\;5\,a_1+4\,a_2,\quad \text{if} \quad a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}^-$$

If so, can we say something about the situation where $\;a_1,\;a_2\;$ have different signs (one positive, one negative)?

Comment: First, a MathJax tip: use `\text{.}` around the `for` and `if`, it'll look better. Now to your questions. Answer to the first one is just 'yes'. As for your second query, why not simply continue doing the case work? You seem to have done fine with that so far.

Comment: When they are both positive or both negative you surely can. Where exactly is your confusion? But when they have different signs you cannot.

Comment: @user3733558 Thanks for the tip :) Regarding your question about the rest, since my major is not mathematics and it does not look as easy as the case I have written :) I do not need to know max and min in that case, but can I claim that when $a_1,a_2$ are of different signs, then the range of the function cannot exceed the domain $(\;-5\,a_1-4\,a_2\;,\;5\,a_1+4\,a_2\;)$ with both $a_1,a_2>0$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks; can I claim that when $a_1,a_2$ are of different signs, then the range of the function cannot exceed the domain $(\;-5\,a_1-4\,a_2\;,\;5\,a_1+4\,a_2\;)$ with both $a_1,a_2>0$

Comment: @Martha97 or you could just use absolute values $(\;-5\,\vert a_1\vert -4\,\vert a_2\vert \;,\;5\,\vert a_1\vert +4\,\vert a_2\vert \;)$.

Comment: @user3733558 So, is that true?

Comment: $$
-2 \;\leq \;f_1(x,y) \;\;\leq 5 \\
\implies \vert f_1(x,y)\vert \leq 5 \\
\implies \vert a_1 \vert \; \vert f_1(x,y)\vert \leq 5 \;\vert a_1 \vert \\
\implies \vert a_1  f_1(x,y)\vert \leq 5 \; \vert a_1 \vert \\
\implies -5 \; \vert a_1 \vert \leq a_1  f_1(x,y) \leq 5 \; \vert a_1 \vert \\
$$
Apply the same to the other inequalities, add up, and you get a range for all $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: @user3733558 Thank you very much.